# When will this condition evaluate to False?

Tags: c

Under what circumstances will the "False" part of the following code be executed?

```
x = 20;
y = -30;
if (x > y) {
    // True part
}
else {
    // False part
}
```

NB: Language is C, compiler is gcc (although some other compilers may also do the same thing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `y` is of unsigned integer type it will be initialized to some very large value (because of how negative integer values are represented) and the comparison expression will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: It's not really "because of how negative integer values are represented", it's because that's how conversion of out-of-range values to unsigned types is defined by the language (it's independent of the representation).

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned int x = 20;
unsigned int y = -30;
```

Sadly, the compiler I'm using doesn't even give a compile-time warning about this.

Comment: @Greg: Oops, my bad :( - I keep getting confused between `signed` and `unsigned`

Answer (score 2):

Only when X and Y are unsigned.

Comment: Actually, only one of them needs to be unsigned - the case I saw it in had `x` as unsigned, but `y` as signed, and the problem still existed.

Answer (score 2):

Even if `x` and `y` are `int`, you could always have the following...

```
#define if(p) if(!(p))
```

...in the body of your method ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry**, this is C++. It's just fun, anyway, so I won't delete unless someone complains.

Needed a little help from `static_cast`, but `static_cast` is safe, right?

```
enum E { ea = 20, eb = -30 } x;
enum F { fa = 20, fb = -30 } y;

bool operator>( E const &l, F const &r )
    { return static_cast<int>(l) < static_cast<int>(r); }

x = static_cast<E>( 20 );
y = static_cast<F>( -30 );
```

or a little looser,

```
enum E { x = 20 };
enum F { y = -30 };

bool operator>( E, F )
    { return false; }
```